# How to start many docker-compose services with different client configs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I have a service defined in docker-compose that I want to deploy for several clients. Several hundred services would run on a group of docker nodes to serve as many client companies. I would like to define some configuration data for each client (i.e application config values or credentials for a DB to read config from). At the minimun I need a service to discover which client company it belongs to.

Can this be done using something like consul.io ?

How would I start each client?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new mysql service for each customer into the docker-compose.yml and yes to distribute your services across multiple nodes you can use consul, it's a good solution.

In docker 1.12 there is a built-in orchestration layer, if you are starting something new feel free to start with it

Comment: How would I choose which client config to use when doing docker-compose up ?

Comment: Sorry maybe I miss something, what do you mean with client? :)